# How do I format text, specifically text links, in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, links, text-formatting

Does anyone know how I would go about putting formatted text in a stream update in Google+? Specifically I'm trying to put text links in a post, without having to show the URL or have the page information below what I write.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you're limited to [formatting bold, italics and strikethroughs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXrpn.jpg) for now.

You've got the following options only at this stage:

```
*Purple* _Monkey_ -Dishwasher-
```

The above will render as this:

> **Purple** *Monkey* <s>Dishwasher</s>

Links added to a stream update will either automatically fetch the image or stick a thumbnail of the page you're linking to in an attachment to the main post.

Comment: How did the people who commented [on this post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107611420709201726294/posts/K9hCzx9PMW4) manage to make a click-able link to a YouTube video?

Comment: When you add in a direct link to a YouTube video, Google+ will automatically format it into a link and display the video title. @gre

Answer (score 7):

There's something I just found.

It's related to posting YouTube videos.

Let's say you are posting a video and you want to make attention at particular part of it.
Just write hours:minutes and Google Plus will automatically create direct link to the video frame.

"**9:15** - blabla" will be linked to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youvideoID#t=**9m15s**

And yes - don't forget to post link to the video itself.

An example: https://plus.google.com/u/0/106412765390072413965/posts/hBa8AWLki8y

Answer (score -3):

To make text BOLD:

```
        Surround the block of text you want bolded with *
        Example: *FREE BEER*   =   FREE BEER
```

To make text ITALIC:

```
        Surround the block of text you want italicized with _
        Example: _Smooth_  Moves   =   Smooth Moves
```

To STRIKETHROUGH text:

```
        Surround the block of text you want to strike through out with –
        Example:  I am -hungry- full   =   I am hungry full
```

Comment: This doesn't offer anything the other answers haven't already covered.