# How to make links in Google Docs comments clickable

Tags: google-docs

In markdown you can make a link [clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/) using a certain syntax (you have GUI options that automated that or you can follow the syntax).

This is great as it hides the ugliness of long urls behind a user friendly name.

My question is: how can we do this in Google Docs comments? If that's not possible, is there a way to provide a *relative* link in Google Docs to the header (as opposed to showing the whole link)?

i.e.

[image]

Comment: Comments automatically link URLs if you put them in. Are you asking how to shorten a URL?

Comment: Allegedly this feature now exists, [per the docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12014036?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cadd-links-with-markdown), though I've not been able to get even their demo to work for me. Open a file in [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

Insert a full URL instead of just the fragment, like `#heading=h.kue93nkjalic`

## Explanation

Google Comments automatically convert inserted full URL to links but it doesn't do the same for anchors. Google Comments use the same formatting than Google+ posts.

- `*bold*`
- `_italic_`
- `-strikethrough-`
- `@name` or `+name` to mention an user

There is no formatting option for URLs, so is you would like to avoid long URLs you should use a URL shortener.

## References

- [Add, edit, reply, or delete comments](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129)
  -[Formatting options for comments](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/L7T5mQiAZ70)
- [What are all the formatting options for a Google+ post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/what-are-all-the-formatting-options-for-a-google-post)
- [How do I format text, specifically text links, in Google+?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17047/how-do-i-format-text-specifically-text-links-in-google)

Comment: I don't care about the URL being long, I care about it not telling me what the link is to.  A link shortener doesn't do that, if anything it makes it worse.  Are you saying there is no way to create arbitrary text that has a link attached to it?